# Google Text-To-Speech for emoji symbols

Tags: java, android, google-text-to-speech

I am working in an application in which we read out the incoming messages for user. Simple text is working fine with Google Text-To-Speech. Is there any way that Google TTS can read out emoji symbols, like Smiley symbol read out as "Smiley", or Heart symbol read out as "Heart"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I fixed up the grammar in your question to make it easier to read and removed the extra request for help at the end, which is already implied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest pre-parsing the strings to replace each instance of an emoji unicode character with a corresponding phrase. This will require you to manually make a list of symbols and corresponding descriptions, but I can't think of a way to get Google TTS to do that on its own.

Comment: Thanks, Could You share some code? it will be very helpful.